# Persisting client side data using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to persist some data between web requests using JavaScript.  I would use Google Gears but I can't install Gears on each client machine or expect it to be installed.  I found this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714420/i-need-to-persist-data-on-the-client-side-about-1m) but I don't like the idea of storing data in that method.  Any suggestions will be welcomed.  Thanks!

Edit:

Ideally I want to store "as much data as possible."  But 1MB is fine.  I'd love for it to work on the major browswer but at least IE/Firefox.

Comment: How much data do you want to store?

Comment: any cross browser requirement?

Comment: Any mitigating scenarios specific to this question which makes it unique from the question you linked?  Otherwise the answer is: See the answers to that question.  What exactly don't you like about those answers?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones it just seems to be a "clueg."  There has to be some supported way that doesn't require a hack like that.

Comment: @Achiles "I want to do X" has never been a reason for X to be possible, especially on the WWW. :)

Comment: @David Dorward that's a good point.  I might be trying something that isn't possible which means I can go back and rethink some design elements, but I'd love to make sure before I scrap this idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you [PersistJS](http://pablotron.org/software/persist-js/), it's a really small library (3K gzipped) for client-side storage, it uses four persistent data solutions depending on the browser capabilities:

- globalStorage: Firefox 2.0+, Internet Explorer 8
- localStorage: development WebKit
- openDatabase: Safari 3.1+
- userdata behavior: Internet Explorer 5.5+

The problem with cookies is that they are limited to about 4 kilobytes in size, and they are sent along with every HTTP request.

Comment: I just came across this in more googling.  Does this data go away after the session ends(browser closed)? Or do I need to spend some effort cleaning up the data?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use cookies.

http://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_cookies.php

Comment: Would you really want to store an significant data in a cookie?

Comment: This won't work as cookies don't allow enough data to be stored (I won't downvote as the answer came before the edit that mentioned the limit).

Answer (score 1):

[LocalStorage](http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2007/01/ajax-performance-local-storage.html) is a new API in HTMTL5 that is being implemented in modern browsers. It is not available in older browsers though.

Comment: It's  unfortunate that IE is strongly lacking in the HTML5 department.

Comment: IE does have an old nonstandard cross page store mechanism so a layer of JS to abstract them might help, however I wonder how many non-IE browsers in common use actually support LocalStorage.