# Maximum length of URL fragments (hash)

Tags: url, hash, fragment-identifier

Is there a length limit for the fragment part of an URL (also known as the *hash*)?

Comment: There is no standard for the hash as it is client-side only, but the limit is generally [very high](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25759637/405550).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is definitely a length for the whole url.

Read

[RFC2616 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html)

[Maximum URL length is 2,083 characters in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)

Comment: RFC2616 doesn't mention fragments except to say: "The URI MUST NOT include a fragment"

Comment: This did not answer the question

Comment: Fragments are client-side. This is not a valid answer.

Answer (score 25):

The hash is client side only, so the rules for HTTP may not apply to it.

Comment: The "hash" is actually the URL Fragment and is not sent to the server, hence the length limitation from a server perspective doesn't apply.

Answer (score 22):

It depends on the browser.
I found that in safari, chrome, and Firefox, an URL with a long hash is legal, but if it is a param send to the server, the browser will display an 414 or 413 error.

for example:
    an URL like `http://www.stackoverflow.com/?abc#{hash value with 100 thousand characters}` will be ok. and you can use location.hash to get the hash value in javascript but an URL like `http://www.stackoverflow.com/?abc&{query with 100 thousand characters}` will be illegal, if you paste this link in the address bar, a 413 error code will be given and the message is `the client issued a request that was too long`. If that is a link in a web page, in my computer, Nginx response the 414 error message.

I don't know the situation in IE.

So I think, the limitation of the length of URL is just for transmission or HTTP server, the browser will check it sometimes, but not every time, and it will always be allowed to be used as a hash.

Comment: Did you find any official (docs) information regarding the client side limitations (or lack thereof)?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the web platform does not have limits on the length of URLs (although 2^31 is a common limit). Chrome limits URLs to a maximum length of 2MB for practical reasons and to avoid causing denial-of-service problems in inter-process communication.